# IR Detector with two indicating leds

Tags: transistors, infrared, basic

I have basic undestanding of electronics, but I never build anything more then simple one element logic boards. I know how transistor, resistors, and LEDs works, but I having trouble figuring out proper specs for each one. Here at home, I'm trying to build simple IR detector with 2 indicator LEDs, it suppose to lid one of red or green if object inside IR detector.

Here is principal schematics attached. IR led (D3) connected with photodiode (PD2), signal from photodiode go to transistor (B139_2) base and which suppose to get open and allow red LED to lid, same signal go to second transistor (BD139_3) base and close it (reversed using lowering resistor), leads to off green LED. And wise-verse to open red and close green.

How to find proper values for transistor (model) and resistor values to make schematics works?

Photodiode BL-L3522PD working on 5V gives output 0.35V when lid, then I need to find proper transistor which opens on 0.35V. And I guess should keep in mind all internal resistance of all elements, like LEDS and transistors. I suppose transistor has to be MOSFET sine I'm not using current to control transistor, but only voltage.

[image: principal schematics]

**Second attempt**.

Almost working. If I connect 5V to the BC547 base it switch the LED's (green / red) just fine. But, for some reason, If I connect PD2 to the BC547 base it turn's the green LED and RED at the same time. Still the same question: how to find correct transistors (not by guessing or googling for similar schematics), and how to get correct resistor values. (I already blew up one transistor, so, be save, it actually blow, ohh!)

EDIT: D3 goes with 220ohm resistor. replacing PD1 with L-7113P3C makes this schematics works. Check youtube link below.

[image]

- https://youtu.be/e1UOlpuMJP4 (now I'm thinking about this solution, and I can't explain how it works, looks like miracle to me).

**Third attempt**.

Using phototransistor L-7113P3C. Using two BC547 transistor's in pair to switch red and green led's.

[image]

Comment: First thing to improve: D1, D2 and D3 each need an own resistor for current control.

Comment: Just a tip: ground symbols should always point towards "the ground" (downwards). The symbol represents conducting plates buried in the earth.

Comment: A photodiode's voltage isn't what you want to consider, but instead the current it can produce/permit when exposed to light. So you don't need to arrange things the way you have. In fact, you probably shouldn't. You don't say, but how much current flows through the photodiode when exposed to your light source? Try using a voltage source and resistor in series the photodiode (arranged in opposition.) Then measure the voltage drop across your known resistor as you change the lighting circumstances. Let us know what you get for "no light" and "light" situations.

Comment: You are still leaving out the resistors needed to control the current in the active devices. D3 is dead at this point and PD1 is responding to the light in the room.

Answer (score 2):

I have drawn a schematic for a simple circuit that will do what you want. When enough light shines on the photo diode, PD1, Q1 turns on enough to hold Q2 off and current flows through R5, D2 to light up LED2. When light is blocked from reaching PD1 , Q1 will turn off, and current from R4 will turn on Q2, sending the current from R5 in to LED1. Since photo diodes produce some current even when not fully illuminated, R3 must be adjusted to make Q1 turn off. R1 and R2 limit the current in their respective diodes.[image]
I have assumed that PD1 only produces a few microamps. If it is more like 100 uA, it can be put in the place of Q1 and R2,3 can be omitted. It is usually necessary to shield the photo diode from ambient light; a short peice of black tubing slipped over the diode is the easiest method. Transistors are any general purpose type: 3904, 2222, BC547, etc.

Comment: Best solution so far! Still no recommended transistors and explanation how exactly does it works (what voltage, which resistors and values come from, hacking is cool, but understanding is nice). I found BC547 (npn) works great with BC557 (pnp). Let's keep digging for best solution, I will share mine when I finish hacking it!.

Comment: Transistors are any general purpose type: 3904, 2222, BC547, etc. Asking for an explanation of all the design decisions involved in even a simple circuit like this is asking me to write a whole book and is not reasonable. I'm afraid your ' hacking ' will be more literal than figurative; it works correctly as shown.

Comment: One question then, why did you connect PD1 to the "+" instead of ground?

Comment: Light shining on a photo diode causes current to flow and this current is opposite to the normal forward direction.

Comment: Thank you for the bonus. I suggest that you build my circuit and measure the voltages as the light varies, starting with R2, then R3, R4, and the LEDs. Use Ohm's law to determine current and think about where it is going. To create your own circuit you need to understand how correctly designed ones work and there is no substitute for measurement and analysis.

Comment: I'm testing my photodiod, something wrong with it. When I build source(5v)+photodiod+resistor(1kom) I measure photodiode V, when it lid with IR, I read 3V, when it is not lid I read 3.45V. When I connect green LED in between I got very weak light (~1mA or less) when photodiod lid with IR, and no LED light when photodiode not lid (0mA). I except get much higher amps enough to turn LED on in full (transistor in my big scheme), but in result, I'm getting micro amps, and nothing working. Can you suggest valid photodiod part number?

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov if you want a circuit that works you can use the one in my answer.

Comment: @Damien Thank you for your option, I will try them all. I want to understand the basics of electronics. I see 3 options so far, phototransistor+BJT, photodiod+MOSFET, and photodiod+opamp. Right now I'm waiting for components to arrive to try them all, but it getting clear now. Most people online confused about difference between photodiod and phototransistor because they looks exactly the same (LED). And do not understand difference between BJT and MOSFET (A vs V). Opamp, in other hand, most expensive solution, gettin me away from understanding the basiscs. Not the one I'm gonig to recommend.

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov I understand the logic, although the days of transistor-based "logic/analog amp" circuitry is gone, unless for really really dirt cheap electronics. Note also that this circuit will have a temperature dependency due to the BJT junction. R5 is too big to light your LEDs, D2 has to match Q2 junction gap and LED 1 & 2 need to have the same junction voltage which probably won't be the case if different colors. This circuit "might" work but there is a lot of tuning to do.

Comment: I constructed and tested this circuit before posting it. I had no trouble in getting satisfactory performance. Your nit pick comments are so typical of the "know it all" garbage one incontures online and are nothing more than sour grapes.

Comment: What I said, I'm having trouble connecting photodiode to BC547, it has no effect. According to wikipedia it even has one article per photodiode and phototransistor, and first vs second one is higher power output. I assumed, only phototransistors can properly works with BJT transistors because of it's "Amp" nature. In my case L-7113P3C works, and BL-L3522PD is not. I googled a lot before to find working schematics and faced the same issue, photodiode not working. I'm still waiting for other components to arrive to test it out (mosfet transistors and opamps) all configurations. What's yours?

Comment: My comment just above was meant for Damien. I also found that the diode I hoped to use didn't produce enough current so I switched to a photo transistor which I got from a VCR. I reduced R3 to 1K and R2 to 3.9K. After I slipped a piece of black tubing over the photo transistor and pointed it at the IR LED, the output would switch color when I put my hand in the way.

Comment: When you say " it has no effect " , what are you measuring?

Answer (score 1):

Your schematic has several issues.

Current needs to be limited in the LEDs, PD2 probably won't be able to drive the BJT and would be very dependent on temperature.

Generally speaking, if you want to convert an analog signal (Your photodiode) to a digital "on/off" signal, the safe choice is to use an [operational amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) in [comparator mode](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/op-amp-comparator.html).

Op-amp is now perhaps the most widely used circuit in all analog systems and has replaced most discrete circuitry.

Using an opamp as a comparator, you can have a trim pot that you can adjust for the level of detection.

Here is a circuit that would achieve your needs.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKXeug.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D2 is your IR LED, D1 your photodiode. A voltage is generated between D1 and R1 which is relative the light received. R3 allows you to adjust the threshold upon which D3 would light up.

[Edit for on/off LEDs as DKNguyen & Dorian mentionned]

Comment: Thanks! But I'm using two output LED's! Whole idea is to use two, not one. And I need good transistor database with full specs where I can find one, which can trigger on .35V

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov That's an issue with your design, not the transistor. You made your design require transistors made of exotic materials for a mundane application. Re-design it so it doesn't. Amplify your photodiode firs or use a phototransistor.

Comment: @DKNguyen ok, ok. I'm learning. Keep booth questions then. What the best way to go? Which model of opamp should I use? How to enable two output LED's? How low transistors threshold voltage can go, is here a transistor database where I can see how many low voltage transistors available? I found BSH103, works on 0.4V... any lower?

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov Transistor thresholds can get pretty low like germanium, I think, but those are expensive, obsolete, or rare and used for things like RF which is why you don't use them unless your application is so low power and noise sensitive that you don't have any other choice. Some ideas for your ORIGINAL circuit: (1) swap out the photodiode for a phototransistor which automatically has more gain (2) build a transimpedance amplifier around the photodiode in your original circuit. For DAMIEN's circuit: you can use the op-amp (or comparator) to drive transistors to drive two LEDs opposite

Comment: Note that in Damien's circuit, the component specified is an op-amp, but it is being used without negative feedback(nothing going from output to the -input) which makes it behave as an unoptimized comparator. A real comparator is similar but is optimized to be fast and in not concerned about being very linear in the intermediate region between full HI and full LO (which is the opposite of an op-amp). That means you would ideally use a comparator instead. For your case it is unlikely to matter though.

Comment: Your solution is actually the best, just add the second LED with the resistor between TLC2272 output and 5v rail and it's perfect. The output is push pull.

Comment: Edited the circuit to have "on / off" leds as @Dorian pointed out.

Comment: To be fair, I noticed later that @DKNguyen mentioned this first

Answer (score 0):

LEDs MUST be current limited.
Connect D1 & D2 upper (Anode) directly to V1.
Add a 1k resistor in series with each of D1 and D2.

Consider adding a 10K pot from V1 to ground with pot wiper to Cathode (now grounded) of detector. Pot can be adjusted to alter "sensitivity".